# Error: HTTP 400 Unable to create record: Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I use the credentials that **Twilio** provides me in the *dashboard*:

[image: dashboard]

Checking that they are the *live* credentials:

[image: tokens]

I also check that the number I want to use is the one that is confirmed in **sandbox**.

[image: sandbox]

I have the following code snippet:

```php
$twilio_number = "+51XXXXXX618";
$client = new \Twilio\Rest\Client(
    'account_sid',
    'auth_token'
);
$message = $client->messages->create(
    "whatsapp:+51XXXXXX148",
    [
        // "from" => "whatsapp:+14155238886",
        "from" => "whatsapp:".$twilio_number,
        "body" => "Prueba de envio de msj"
    ]
);
```

And I get the following error (code in php):

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In your code you appear to be trying to send a message from the number that starts +51.

That number is a participant in your sandbox, but that means you can send messages *to* that number, not *from* it. When you are using the Twilio WhatsApp sandbox you can only send messages from your sandbox number, the one starting +1415.

To move on from the sandbox, you need to [follow these instructions to register a number with WhatsApp that you can use for your business](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/connect-number-business-profile).